# Chiliproject / redmine: cannot start thin on init

Tags: linux, redmine

I have been tasked with putting a chiliproject instance back online. It is running on a CentOS 6 (64 bits) server. The problem is, I know absolutely zero Ruby, and my Linux knowledge isn't much more advanced than that; I have absolutely no idea where to start.

When I load the page on a browser, the following gets written to `/var/log/nginx/redmine-proxy-error`:

```
2014/01/13 11:52:06 [crit] 1865#0: *675 connect() to unix:/var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.3.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: IPADDRESSHERE, server: REDACTED.com.br, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.3.sock:/", host: "REDACTED.com.br"
2014/01/13 11:52:06 [crit] 1865#0: *675 connect() to unix:/var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.0.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: IPADDRESSHERE, server: REDACTED.com.br, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.0.sock:/", host: "REDACTED.com.br"
2014/01/13 11:52:06 [crit] 1865#0: *675 connect() to unix:/var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.1.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: IPADDRESSHERE, server: REDACTED.com.br, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.1.sock:/", host: "REDACTED.com.br"
2014/01/13 11:52:06 [crit] 1865#0: *675 connect() to unix:/var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.2.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: IPADDRESSHERE, server: REDACTED.com.br, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.2.sock:/", host: "REDACTED.com.br"
```

I got some help from #chiliproject on IRC:

> `thin` is an app server which (in your case) seems to be tasked to run the actual chiliproject code. It has to be started seperately from nginx, and should then (according to your config) create a listening socket at /var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.3.sock where your nginx forwards connections to. You might have a seperate init script for thin already. Or else you might have to start it using script/server or the thin executable inside your chiliproject dir. You probably have a thin config file somewhere (something like redmine.yml, e.g. in /etc/thin), it should contain (in human readable form) some config settings for thin, including the socket location, your chiliproject directory and other stuff. You can start thin by running `thin start -C /etc/thin/redmine.yml`

Here is my `/etc/thin/redmine.yml` (the only file on this dir):

```
--- 
chdir: /srv/www/redmine/chiliproject
environment: production
timeout: 30
log: /var/log/redmine/thin.log
pid: /var/run/redmine/pids/thin.pid
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 100
require: []

wait: 30
servers: 4
socket: /var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.sock
daemonize: true
user: redmine
group: redmine
```

And here's `/etc/rc.d/init.d/thin`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          thin
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      S 0 1 6
# Short-Description: thin initscript
# Description:       thin
### END INIT INFO

# Original author: Forrest Robertson

# Do NOT "set -e"

DAEMON=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/thin
#DAEMON=/usr/local/rvm/bin/bootup_thin
SCRIPT_NAME=/etc/init.d/thin
#CONFIG_PATH=/etc/thin
CONFIG_PATH=/etc/thin/redmine.yml

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

case "$1" in
  start)
    #$DAEMON start --all $CONFIG_PATH
    $DAEMON start -C /etc/thin/redmine.yml
    ;;
  stop)
    $DAEMON stop --all $CONFIG_PATH
    ;;
  restart)
    $DAEMON restart --all $CONFIG_PATH
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME {start|stop|restart}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```

There is no `/usr/local/rvm/bin/bootup_thin` file.

I reboot the machine and run `ps aux | grep thin` it shows me nothing (besides the grep itself).

If I execute `start -C /etc/thin/redmine.yml` I get a text output on screen and thin starts and I can browse the site. If I reboot the machine, the service will not load properly, despite the `init.d` file. This file is being executed, because I have placed a `touch /var/log/test` line on the `start)` clause and the file is created. I have also appended `> /var/log/thin_output` to the end of the start line, but it creates and empty file, and the `thin` logs do not show it being started.

Including `start -C /etc/thin/redmine.yml` at the end of `/etc/rc.local` also has no effect.

The output of `type thin` is

> thin is /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/thin

If I type `/etc/init.d/thin start` it will start with a normal output:

```
Starting server on /var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.0.sock ...
Starting server on /var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.1.sock ...
Starting server on /var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.2.sock ...
Starting server on /var/run/redmine/sockets/thin.3.sock ...
```

I was asked on chat to paste the output of `find -L /etc/ -samefile /etc/init.d/thin`, it is:

```
/etc/rc2.d/K50thin
/etc/rc0.d/K50thin
/etc/rc5.d/K50thin
/etc/init.d/thin
/etc/rc.d/rc2.d/K50thin
/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/K50thin
/etc/rc.d/rc5.d/K50thin
/etc/rc.d/init.d/thin
/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/K50thin
/etc/rc.d/rc1.d/K50thin
/etc/rc.d/rc4.d/K50thin
/etc/rc.d/rc6.d/K50thin
/etc/rc3.d/K50thin
/etc/rc1.d/K50thin
/etc/rc4.d/K50thin
/etc/rc6.d/K50thin
```

I did perform `sudo chkconfig thin on` as suggested in an answer here, and `chkconfig -l thin` outputs

> thin                      0:off  1:off  2:on  3:on  4:on  5:on  6:off

and the output of `find -L /etc/ -samefile /etc/init.d/thin` changes to `/etc/rc2.d/S50thin /etc/rc0.d/K50thin /etc/rc5.d/S50thin /etc/init.d/thin /etc/rc.d/rc2.d/S50thin /etc/rc.d/rc0.d/K50thin /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/S50thin /etc/rc.d/init.d/thin /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S50thin /etc/rc.d/rc1.d/K50thin /etc/rc.d/rc4.d/S50thin /etc/rc.d/rc6.d/K50thin /etc/rc3.d/S50thin /etc/rc1.d/K50thin /etc/rc4.d/S50thin /etc/rc6.d/K50thin`; but when I reboot, thin is still not running.

Someone suggested me to compare the environment variables on different runlevels, so I included `printenv > /var/log/printenv.log` on a line of `/etc/rc.d/init.d/thin` and compared it to the output of `printenv` on the CLI. Here's the results:

```
TERM=linux
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
RUNLEVEL=3
runlevel=3
PWD=/
LANGSH_SOURCED=1
LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
PREVLEVEL=N
previous=N
CONSOLETYPE=vt
SHLVL=2
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
UPSTART_EVENTS=runlevel
UPSTART_JOB=rc
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

and

```
rvm_bin_path=/usr/local/rvm/bin
HOSTNAME=redacted.com.br
GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=1000
IRBRC=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/.irbrc
SSH_CLIENT=REDACTED
OLDPWD=/etc
MY_RUBY_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
__array_start=0
rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm
escape_flag=1
rvm_prefix=/usr/local
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PWD=/
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
LANG=pt_BR.utf8
_second=1
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
rvm_version=1.16.17 (stable)
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
_first=0
LOGNAME=root
CVS_RSH=ssh
GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
SSH_CONNECTION=REDACTED
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-1.9.2-p290
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Comment: The solution to this issue is simple: don't reboot the machine. Ever.

Comment: Nooooo! Migrated to SF! Downvotes in 3... 2... 1...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your environmet variables seems to indicate your server is using the [Ruby Version Manager](http://rvm.io/):

> Ruby Version Manager, often abbreviated as RVM, is a unix-like software platform designed to manage multiple installations of Ruby on the same device.
>
> The entire ruby environment including the Ruby interpreter, installed RubyGems, and documentation is partitioned. The different versions can then be switched between to enable a developer to work on several projects with different version requirements.

Apparently RVM  isn't included in your boot environment. You may easily solve it reinstalling the service again:

First, update your RVM to the latest version

> rvm get stable

Then, perform these steps

1. create init.d entry for thin

   ```
    sudo thin install
   ```
2. set up some defaults

   ```
    sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f thin defaults
   ```
3. generate boot config for your rails app

   ```
    sudo thin config -C /etc/thin/<appname>.yml -c /var/rails/<appdir> --servers 4 -e production
   ```
4. generate rvm wrapper script

   ```
    rvm wrapper <rubyversion>@<gemset> bootup thin
   ```
5. If you're using a global gemset, you can just use

   ```
    rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.2-p125 bootup thin
   ```
6. edit thin init

   ```
    sudo nano /etc/init.d/thin
   ```
7. change the original loader

   ```
    DAEMON=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-<rubyversion>-<rubyrevision>@<gemset>/bin/thin
   ```
8. to point to the rvm wrapper instead

   ```
    DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/bootup_thin
   ```
9. start it up

   ```
    sudo /etc/init.d/thin start
   ```

Now it should start when your system boots up.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3376785/792066